# Observer Watching a Ball Thrown Up on A Train

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertial-frames, observers, relative-motion, galilean-relativity

Let's suppose I'm on a train, moving with constant speed ***V1***. At a time ***T1*** I throw a ball up in the air, the ball do not accelerate but has constant velocity ***V2***, and, in this hypotetical scenario, **no force of gravity is experienced by the ball.**
At a time **T2** the ball reaches the roof of the train, which is located at a distance ***d***  on the z-axis, from the point I have thrown the ball.[image]

A friend of mine, is watching on the platform. He sees the ball being thrown at ***T1***, and then the train travelling a distance ***V1***(***T2***-***T1***).

- Is it right to say he sees the ball moving along a diagonal path $\sqrt {d^2+(V_1(T_2-T_1))^2}$?
- What about the speed he sees the ball moving?

If there is any problem please comment below, and I will try to edit the question.

Comment: If the ball/train is on Earth and you throw it up in the air it will have acceleration downwards due to gravity.

Comment: Can't I imagine an hypotetic situation whit a train moving and me thowring a ball without gravity?

Comment: You _can_; but it's an extremely odd assumption to make for a "throwing the ball in the air" type problem.  It wasn't clear that you were making that assumption, it seemed more likely to me that you just forgot about it.  I suggest explicitly stating that in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciated a lot your comments! I tried to make it as clear as I can think of. If you have any other advice I'm happy to listen to them!

Comment: The speed he sees the ball moving is V1 in the x(horizontal) direction and V2 in the y(vertical) direction or Vt = $\sqrt {V1^2 + V2^2}$

Comment: are we dealing with relativistic ball and train?

Comment: I don't get the put "On hold",I would love someone to explain it:  1) Question is not off-Topic, It seems to me that it's a quesiton about a clearly stated physics scenario 2) Question is upvoted and so useful for the community 3)Question is no way an Homework Question since it's about an hypotetical scenario, imagined by me based on  prevoius knowledge and spirit of curiosity 4) Quesion is clearly the product of some effort done in making it, with pictures and hypotetical solutions provided. So if you do put on hold a question you at least take time to give a proper reason

Comment: @ Brad S to me it does not seem to be so, since it's not relativistic @Chaitanya Murthy, the time of when an observer on the platform  see it touching the ceiling and one  outside is the same. am I wrong?

Comment: Is the friend on the platform on the train or off the train?